# Named values: what if 2 values have same name

Tags: r

For a vector of named values `vec = 1:3`, `names(vec) = c('x1','x2','x1')`, how R deals with different values with the same name? For example `vec['x1']` only returns the first value named 'x1'. What if I want to access other values with the same name? Though it's not a good idea to have different objects sharing the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to Ananda's suggestion, I would fix your naming ASAP:

```
names(vec)<-make.names(names(vec),unique=TRUE)

#  x1   x2 x1.1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `%in%` for cases when there would be multiple matches, but yes, it's not a good idea to have different objects sharing the same name.

```
> vec[names(vec) %in% "x1"]
x1 x1 
 1  3
```